# How do I paginate to the next page in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How do I paginate to the next page in selenium python?

Code trials:

```
import os,json,requests, time
from pprint import pprint
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Cordless-Drills/184655/bn_9863722?rt=nc&_dmd=1')
time.sleep(0.5)


links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="s-item__wrapper clearfix"]//a[@class="s-item__link"]')
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: does this answer your question ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59251187/how-to-paginate-in-selenium-python

Answer (score 0):

To paginate to the next page you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Cordless-Drills/184655/bn_9863722?rt=nc&_dmd=1')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#gdpr-banner-accept[aria-label='Accept privacy terms and settings']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.ebayui-pagination__li.ebayui-pagination__li--selected +li > a"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Cordless-Drills/184655/bn_9863722?rt=nc&_dmd=1')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='gdpr-banner-accept']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='ebayui-pagination__li ebayui-pagination__li--selected']//following::li[1]/a"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: ebay_uk_page2]